# Neo4j and concurrent writes, how to handle deadlock issues, preferably server-side?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm running into issues with deadlocks during concurrent merge operations (REST API).  I have a function that processes text with some metadata, and for each item in the metadata dictionary, I'm performing a merge to add either a node or connect the text node with the metadata[n] node.  Issues come up when the message rate is around 500-1000 per second.

In this particular function, there are 11 merges between 6 queries, which go something like this:

```
q1 = "MERGE (n:N { id: {id} }) ON CREATE SET ... ON MATCH SET "
     "WITH . MERGE (...) "
     "WITH ., . MERGE (.)-[:some_rel]->(.)"
params = {'the': 'params'}
cypher.execute(q1, params)

if some_condition:
    q2 = "MATCH (n:N { id: {id} }) ... "
         "WITH n, . MERGE (n)-[:some_rel]->(.)"
    params = {'more': 'params'}
    cypher.execute(q2, params)

 if some_condition2:
     q3
 ...
 if some_condition_n:
     qn
```

I'm running the above with Python, via Celery (for those not familiar with Celery, it's a distributed task queue).  When the issue first came up, I was executing the above in a single transaction, and had a ton of failures due to deadlock exceptions.  My initial thought was simply to implement a distributed blocking lock at the function level with Redis.  This, however, causes a bottleneck in my app.

Next, I switched from a single Cypher transaction a few atomic transactions as in the above and removed the lock.  This takes care of the bottleneck, as well as greatly reducing the number of deadlock exceptions, but they're still occurring, albeit at the reduced level.

Graph databases aren't really my thing, so I don't have a ton of experience with the in's and out's of Neo4j and Cypher.  I have a secondary-index in Redis of the uuid's of existing nodes, so there is a pre-processing step prior to the merge's to try and keep the graph access down.  Are there any obvious solutions that I should try?  Maybe there's some way to queue the operations on the graph-side, or maybe I'm overlooking some server optimizations?  Any advice on where to look would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue, mainly that there wasn't an issue to begin with.  [That is:](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/148cct14c5/locking-differences-between-enterprise-and-community)

> The Enterprise version of Neo4j has an alternative lock manager than
>   the Community version, meant to provide scalable locking on
>   high-CPU-count machines.
>
> The Enterprise Lock Manager uses a deadlock detection algorithm that
>   does not require (much) synchronization, which gives it some very
>   desirable scalability attributes. The drawback is that it may
>   sometimes detect false-positives. This normally does not happen in
>   production usage, but becomes evident in stress testing individual
>   operations. These scenarios see much lower churn in CPU cache
>   invalidation, which the enterprise lock manager needs to communicate
>   across cores.
>
> As a deadlock detection error is a safe-to-retry error and the user is
>   expected to handle these in all application code, since there may be
>   legitimate deadlocks at any time, this behavior is actually by design
>   to gain scalability.

I simply caught the exception and then retry after a few seconds and now:

[image: success]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after thinking about this some more, I realized that the way my queries were executed was inefficient and could do with some refactoring.  Since all the queries are within the same general context, there is no reason to execute them all individually, or even no reason to open a transaction and have them executed that way.

Instead, I changed function to go through the conditionals, and concatenate the query strings into one long string, and add the params that I need to the param dictionary.  So, now, there's only one execution at the end, with one statement.  This also takes out some of the 'MATCH' statements.

This fix doesn't wholly fix the issue, though, as there are still some deadlock exceptions being thrown.